# Implementing nub (distinct)

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel

I've implemented the following `nub'` or "give distinct elements of list" function:

```
nub' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
nub' [] = []
nub' xs = nubHelper xs []

nubHelper :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
nubHelper []     acc = acc
nubHelper (y:ys) acc = if(contains y acc)  
                         then nubHelper ys acc 
                         else nubHelper ys (acc ++ [y])
                         where contains match acc = 
                            foldl (\as x -> if(y == x) then True else as) False acc
```

Example:

```
*Main> nub' [1,2,1,1,1,1,3,4,3,1]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Surely there must be a cleaner way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the "official" answer, you can go straight to the [GHC source for `nub`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/src/Data-List.html#nub):

```
nub                     :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
nub l                   = nub' l []
  where
    nub' [] _           = []
    nub' (x:xs) ls
        | x `elem` ls   = nub' xs ls
        | otherwise     = x : nub' xs (x:ls)
```

Some of the differences that stand out are:

- Use a `where` clause to scope your helper function, and name it with a "prime" symbol.  In your case, I guess the helper would be `nub''`.  The helper's type can then be automatically inferred.
- Use pattern matching instead of if-then-else.
- Your `contains` helper is just the `elem` builtin.  They chose to write `` x `elem` ls `` instead of `elem x ls`, probably to read more smoothly.
- It's more natural / efficient to prepend than to append elements to a list.  Instead of building `acc` as the result as a list of wanted elements, they build `ls` as the list of elements to exclude in future encounters.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, @200_success. Could you please say more to `It's more natural / efficient to prepend than to append elements to a list`?

Comment: Think of them as singly linked lists: manipulating the head is guaranteed to be trivial; operations on the tail might not be. (We don't know _exactly_ how the lists are implemented. There might be optimizations that make operations on the tail efficient, but you shouldn't rely on the existence of such optimizations.) With that in mind, see [How to work on lists](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_work_on_lists#Notes_about_speed). Prepend (`:`) is guaranteed to be a fast operation, but Concatenate (`++`) isn't.

Comment: thanks. From a style point of view, is the padding, required for each `=` to align, considered best practice?

Comment: I can't really say. The [Haskell style guide](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Programming_guidelines) stays silent on the issue.

Answer (score 4):

3 lines using `filter`.

```
nub' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
nub' [] = []
nub' (x:xs) = x : nub' (filter (/=x) xs)
```

### Explanation

What I'm doing here can be explained in the following:

1. Separate the input as `x:xs` using pattern matching. So, `x` is the first lement of the list and `xs` will be rest of the list.
2. Concat the first element `x` with a `nub` of filtered list of `xs` that 
   do not contain `x`.

#### Performance

In terms of performance, I'm not sure if this is the same as the one implemented in the GHC source code.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and why it is better than the original) so that the author and other readers can learn from your thought process.