# Implementing Transpose

Tags: haskell, matrix, reinventing-the-wheel

I'm implementing `transpose` in Haskell.

```
-- transpose [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]  
-- [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

Please give it a look. Note that I'm trying not to use any built-in functions (excluding `map` and `++`):

```
transpose' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose' ys
   | null $ filter (not . null) ys = []
   | otherwise = [flatten' $ map head' ys] ++ transpose' (map tail' ys)

head' :: [a] -> [a]
head' []     = []
head' (x:xs) = [x]

tail' :: [a] -> [a]
tail' []     = []
tail' (x:xs) = xs

flatten' :: [[a]] -> [a]
flatten' as = foldl (\acc x -> acc ++ x)  [] as
```

Side note - I know that I could look at the Haskell source, but I appreciate the comments & thoughtful insights here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see a few problems, mostly similar to my [remarks in a previous answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/48104/9357):

1. Your definition of `head'` is unconventional.  Its definition should be

   ```
   head' :: [a] -> a
   head (x:_) = x
   ```

   Furthermore, your problematic definition of `head'` is making you define `flatten'`.  If you fix `head'` as suggested above, then`flatten'` becomes unnecessary.
2. The definition of `tail'` is too complicated.  It could just be

   ```
   tail' :: [a] -> [a]
   tail (_:xs) = xs
   ```
3. For clarity, I would rename the parameter to `transpose'` from `ys` to `rows`.
4. The base case of `transpose'` is too complicated.  Also, it can be done using pattern matching.

   ```
   transpose' [[]]    = []
   transpose' [[], _] = []
   ```
5. Prefer `x:xs` to `[x] ++ xs`.
6. Scope your helper functions using `where`.

Here's what I came up with:

```
transpose' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose' [[]]    = []
transpose' [[], _] = []
transpose' rows    = (map head' rows) : transpose' (map tail' rows)
  where
    head' (x:_) = x
    tail' (_:xs) = xs
```

Comment: I tested the code `transpose' [[1,2],[4,4],[8,9]]`, Non-exhaustive patterns in function head'

Answer (score 3):

Good job doing it the hard way. Definitely take a peek at the implementations of functions in `base` after you're done rewriting them though, understanding the "canonical" implementation will do a lot to help you develop an idiomatic style.

1. Your definition of `head'` is non-standard. Here's the signature of `head` from the Prelude.

   ```
   head :: [a] -> a
   ```

   Your version isn't wrong per se, it's valid to return a list of 0 elements for a computation that may fail, but usually only when success will return 1 *or more* elements. The standard way to write `safeHead` is to encode failure using `Maybe` like so.

   ```
   head' :: [a] -> Maybe a
   head' []    = Nothing
   head' (x:_) = Just x
   ```

   This is the 'smallest' correct definition, in the sense of not including additional unnecessary functionality.
2. Replace the identifiers for unused arguments/patterns with an underscore (like I did just above). This can be helpful in catching some subtle errors early if you compile with `-fwarn-unused-matches` (included in `-Wall`). Here's a good [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14309605/1722055) about when that might be the case, and it's a good habit to have even for simpler functions like this.
3. Here's where looking at the docs afterward can help, your function `flatten'` is named `concat` in the standard `List` functions. And in fact mapping over a list and then flattening it is so common that there's even a function for that, creatively named `concatMap`.
4. Consider the lambda you use in the definition of `flatten'`.

   ```
   (\acc x -> acc ++ x)
   ```

   The strength of functional languages is being able to pass functions as values, which is of course what you're doing here with a lambda, but did you know that operators like `++` can already be used like any other old function? Wrap infix operators in parentheses to treat them like regular functions.

   ```
   ... = foldl (++) [] as -- Identical to the above!
   ```
5. [`foldl` is broken!](http://www.well-typed.com/blog/90/) This might be more advanced reading than you're comfortable with now, but the bottom line is that `foldl` typically has unwanted performance characteristics, and to be safe you should use `foldl'` (`import Data.List (foldl')` at the start of your file, then change all `foldl`s to `foldl'`s) or `foldr`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a surprisingly tricky function.  I played with the solutions provided and realized they were not generic.  For instance, the solution that only relies on `fmap` (a.k.a `map` if applied to a list), only worked with a list with two lists (i.e., `[[],_]` only works on a list length of two).

Here is a solution that builds on what was provided to generalize it to a list of *any number of lists*.

```
trans :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
trans [] = []
trans ([]:xss) = trans xss
trans ((x:xs):xss) = (x : fmap head' xss) : trans (xs : fmap tail' xss)
    where head' (x:_) = x
          tail' (_:xs) = xs
```

The benefits of this approach:

1. there is no need to pattern match a list of empty lists; a surprisingly verbose approach that requires the use of a reduction such as `concat`.  Part of the trick to avoiding this is the `([]:xss) = trans xss` recursion.
2. the `trans ((x:xs):xss)` is key to the solution. This pattern match and subsequent reassembly is a useful idiom worth being familiar with.
3. the approach avoids having to define `safehead`; the safeguard of calling `head` on an empty list is moot because we have `trans [] = []` which will pattern match before `xss` reaches a call to `head'`.

What made it tricky was my being stuck on trying to pattern match a list of empty lists e.g., `[[],[],[]]`.    I could not find a way to pattern match on a list of empty lists for any number of empty lists *without* resorting to using `concat xss` with a pattern match to `[]`.